# How to debug an Excel Auto-Open macro before executing it?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I'm being asked to fix an Excel workbook where macros aren't working properly. The workbook includes an Auto-Open macro that changes content, including hiding or removing worksheets, and once it has run through, a second run always crashes because it's trying to select a worksheet previously deleted.

I want to step through Auto-Open but here's the catch:
If I open the workbook and choose to disable macros the macros is not viewable.
If I open the workbook and choose NOT to disable macros Auto-Open runs before I can stop it.

How can I step through Auto-Open on its first run?

Comment: Disabling macros should not stop you viewing them.

Comment: I agree.  If I have macros disabled and try to view macros I see options to 'Run' or 'Step into' along with disabled (greyed out) options of 'Edit', 'Create', Delete, and 'Options...' If I choose 'Step into' I get a dialog message telling me I must reopen the workbook and choose to enable macros.

Comment: @BrianLowe Press Alt+F11 to open the VB Editor. And you should see the macros even if they were disabled.

Comment: Alt-F11 opens a macro editor but no macros are loaded, so I'm still lost. :(

Comment: Click on VBAProject + plus sign to view the sheet and modules.

Comment: You can add `Stop` before the second run. Then open the workbook and choose not to disable, the code will halt at stop line and will allow you to debug.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still no luck... I can open the VBA Project and see the tree view of Microsoft Excel Objects (1 per worksheet plus 'This Workbook') and Modules (2 empty modules). Selecting each worksheet, 'this workbook' and each module in turn gives me a blank content view pane.

Comment: [Open File Within Excel Instance While Holding `Shift'](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/stop-running-open-excel-spreadsheets-77491.html) - Read the details in this link.

Comment: `Workbook_Open` will be in **ThisWorkbook** under **Microsoft Excel Object**. Double click it and it will show you the method on the right side of the editor. If that doesn't work, you will find two `DropDowns` in the right hand pan.. select **Workbook** in the first dropdown and **Open** in the second dropdown

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Holding Ctrl while selecting the file to open gets me the same disabled macros as before.

Comment: @Santosh The workbook is generated by an app with content inserted which the macros operate on so after Auto-Open has run the data and content is changed beyond usefulness so stopping before a second run doesn't let mee see what the macro is operating on.

Comment: @BrianLowe - Please follow the instructions **exactly** as they are written in the article I pointed too. The section called **Opening Without Automatic Macros**. They will work. I promise. I have used this feature many times.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying. Opening the workbook with macros disabled (either by using Ctrl when selecting in the File>Open dialog or responding to the security message on opening) does load the macros, but selecting the worksheet or 'ThisWorkbook' in the tree view isn't enough. I had to right-click in that tree view and select 'View code' to see the code in the right hand panel. Even then, because macros are disabled I can't step through.

Comment: @BrianLowe Of course it does not work if you press `Ctrl` and not as **exactly** described in the link `Shift`!

Answer (score 2):

Full answer trail is in the comments.

Macros are available for editing or debugging when disabled, but you need to use the right-click context menu in the expanded tree view of Microsoft Excel Objects to load the code into the edit panel (a single click shows an empty panel).

I put a "Stop" as the first command in the Auto-Open macro and saved the workbook. On re-opening the workbook I can choose to enable macros and let Auto-Open run, and jump straight into the debugger to step through on a first run.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Debug.Assert False`

You can just insert this as your first line in the auto-open subroutine

`Debug.Assert Condition` will stop the code and prompt debug if `Condition = False`